# Conditions by which a differential map is a globally one-to-one

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ 
be a diffrential map s.t $Df$ is non singular on $B$, where $B$ is an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$. 
What are some necessary and sufficient conditions by which $f$ is one-to-one on $B$? 
Also, if I replace $B$ with an arbitrary open set, what are the conditions then?

Thanks a lot,
Gil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$ this is automatic essentially by the fundamental theorem of calculus.  However, for $n\geq 2$ there is no local condition that would ensure injectivity.  Consider for example the restriction of the exponential map $z\mapsto e^z$ to a narrow open strip around the imaginary axis. The strip gets wrapped around a neighborhood of the unit circle and there is no hope of injectivity unless a global condition is added.

Comment: Thanks for that.

I am aware that $Df \ne 0$ is not enough. What I'm looking for are some examples of sufficient "natural" conditions. For example, if $f=(f_1,..,f_n)$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x_j^2}$ are continuous on the closure of $B(a,R)$ (meaning $a$ and $R$ are the center and the radius). Then, we can put $\max_{1\le i,j \le n,a\in \bar{B}}\frac{ \partial^2 f_j}{\partial x_i^2}(a) =K$ and then if the radius of B is not bigger than a constant depending on $||Df^{-1}(a)||$ and $K$ this is such a condition. 
However, writing this it feels my question is not so well defined.